# Nearest Neighbour on route vs Shortest Path

Tags: pyqgis, shortest-path, travelling-salesman

I have a line layer “Cables” which represents my network, and this is formatted correctly so all lines are in the correct direction. I have a node layer “nodes” that sit directly on top of the lines. I want find each nodes closest neighbour in a backwards direction and draw the cable between them in line with the network route.

Currently I can do this in python using the shortest path point to point processing, and run it for each node against all the other nodes and only take the shortest path. Problem is it’s VERY slow as I have thousands of nodes.

For my task, am I better finding the nearest neighbour first, then draw the routes or should I be building a graph and using Djerka?

Comment: Are you using the spatial index? How heavy is your data? What if you preselect some features from the network layer each time you execute the "Shortest path (point to point)" alg, probably you do not need the whole network each time, init?